# JSP Parameter in SQL

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to get the stock down with one unit every time a product it's bought but I can't update the database. How can I use the JSP parameter in SQL?

```
<%= request.getParameter("item_code") %> and price
<%= request.getParameter("item_price") %> 

<sql:query var="result">
   select item_stock_count from inventory 
      where item_code="item_code";
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try to declare the item_code in a separate variable and then , try this approach

```
<%! int item_code = request.getParameter("item_code");%>
    <sql:query var="as_you_like"
                 sql="UPDATE inventory SET stock = stock-1 where item_code = ?" >
                <sql:param value="${item_code}" />
     </sql:query>
```

**NB** : please try as much as you can to avoid `sql` logic code in your view !! so that it could be easy to maintain your application